# Are there any reasons to not use async script elements?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

Despite the continued adoption of the script element's `async` attribute, there is continued advice to place script at the bottom of the document without the async attribute. If `document.write` is avoided, are there any possible pitfalls when using async?

For example, if I load a script that I wrap in jQuery's `$(document).ready(...)`, is there any chance that I might experience any negative effects when adding the async attribute? Can I reliably specify async on all such scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your scripts rely on being run in a particular order you cannot use `async`. This typically means that they rely on each other.

A recent example of this that happened to me was using Google's prettyprint syntax highlighting library. You include the library and then make a call to `prettyPrint()` to apply the syntax highlighting to relevant blocks.

```
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/prettify.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>prettyPrint();</script>
```

So if all your scripts are wrapped in a `$(document).ready` then they are most likely perfectly fine to go with `async`. The question you should be asking though is whether you can combine all your files so you only need to make one request.

---

The `defer` attribute is similar to `async` but waits until the HTML is parsed and then runs the scripts in the same order that they appear in your HTML file. This would work in the above situation provided the call the `prettyPrint()` was external instead of inline as I don't believe it applies to inline scripts.